# Sharing classes between GWT and AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I use AppEngine (Java) and GWT to design my app.  I have a class that represents objects that both the client (GWT) and the server (AppEngine) act on.  Right now I have a AppEngine class (which contains all the server side information) and a class in the shared directory that the client uses (and gets passed between RPC calls).  Now I need methods that convert between the two, and reproduce methods needed on the server and the client.  This has be come a headache and I see bugs being prone when the class get more complicated.

The reason I didn't just make one shared class is that I didn't want to expose some of my server said logic, methods and attributes to the client.  But I was reading that when GWT compiles it drops unused methods, and attributes from the compiled code.  Is this true, and will this protect the code that I don't want to be seen on the client?  Are there any gotchas I should be aware of?  Attributes are less of a worry (I think) since it'll obfuscate the names.  I know I can use the transient keyword so server data doesn't get sent to the client in RPC calls.

What would be best is an annotation I can put on methods that lets the GWT compiler know that it should never compile this method, that way I know it will never make it in to the compiled javascript.

Lastly if I keep the code separated is there a best practice for cases like this?

Comment: See the answer for your similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184881/annotation-for-gwt-compiler-to-ignore-method/13185612

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I would say that is not a good design. Serialized objects in the shared directory should be pure POJOs and you should not mix business logic in these classes.

Comment: Actually I think you are wrong.  If I need a cat on the server and a cat on the client side why should I have a ClientCat class, and a ServerCat class and then a CatDTO just to transfer a ClientCat to a ServerCat.  All the cat's meow, eat and sleep so I would have to write all those methods atleast twice, the only difference is The ServerCat has some actions that will only be performed on the server and I don't want it shared with the user.  This seems like it would be a good design.

Answer (score 0):

I found one workaround that mostly solves my problem.

I may have a class that calls a server component of my code, this will make GWT compile crash because it doesn't have access to that class (say it is com.myproject.server.Class1).  I can override a package implementation in GWT in the gwt.xml file (seen here http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/DevGuideModuleXml) and make a com.myproject.client.com.myproject.server.Class1 class that implements the methods being called but can return null.  This way GWT has a class to link that it can compile.  Later in the GWT compile it should just drop this class/methods because it never (hopefully) gets called in GWT.

This is probably a pretty hackish workaround but if done carefully can work.