# Annotation for GWT compiler to ignore method

Tags: java, gwt

Is it possible to create an annotation (or some other way) to force the GWT compiler to not compile a method?  I have a class that I also use on app-engine (in a shared folder) and one method in it requires a server side only function which causes GWT to not compile.  I would like GWT to just ignore the method (while appengine does not).

I figured either an annotation, or a pre-compile script that erases the method prior to compilation.  Both methods would work for me, it would be best if I could still compile through the eclipse IDE.

Anyone else thought of this or tried it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not until now. Very recently such annotation was added `@com.google.gwt.core.shared.GwtIncompatible("Description why...")`. It is applicable on classes or methods.

But the patched code was not released yet! Official status is `FixedNotReleased`. And i can personally confirm, it is not in current GWT 2.5.1 version. I am hopeful for upcoming 2.5.2.

See:

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/core/shared/GwtIncompatible.java?spec=svn11570&r=11570

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=3769

https://gwt-review.googlesource.com/#/c/2320/

Note, there is already similar annotation `com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.annotations.GwtIncompatible` in `gwt-dev.jar`, however
it does not work, compiler still wants to compile my *incompatible* method in shared class.

Comment: This is officially coming in GWT 2.6: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZdMwcTjc4rkWg6nntCY1BDB1xI2PHPwaCnTYw-9uAKE/edit

Comment: @GwtIncompatible is part of GWT 2.8.x (which has a stable release, maybe even earlier versions)

Answer (score 7):

Prior to GWT version 2.6, there is no annotation to make the GWT compiler ignore a method. There is a [requests](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=3769) for it in the GWT issue tracker, and apparently it is scheduled for the 2.6 release.

One workaround approach is to have the "offending" method in a class of its own and ignore that class in your `.gwt.xml` file:

```
<source path="gwtclient">
   <exclude name="AppEngineOnlyClass.java" />
   ...
</source>
...
```

Hope that helps a bit.

Cheers,

Comment: Note that `AppEngineOnlyClass` can extend the `AppEngineAndGwtClass` to inherit everything that's valid for both GWT and GAE.